# QGIS iface.reloadConnections() returns errors

Tags: pyqgis

I have been using the following Python code to automate and add several WMS connections to QGIS.  My most recent attempt at executing the code returned an error and I have confirmed that the error exists at `iface.reloadConnections()`.  I can confirm that I get the error on QGIS v3.22 (Windows) and v3.26 (Ubuntu).  I see [here](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#ab96a4046ab4094f329c44e8658871e14) that reloadConnections() is still valid syntax.

Why am I getting the error posted below?

Here is a shortened version of the code.

```
sources = []
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Google Satellite", "", "", "", "https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D", "", "19", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Stamen Terrain", "", "", "Map tiles by Stamen Design, under CC BY 3.0. Data by OpenStreetMap, under ODbL", "http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png", "", "20", "0"])
sources.append(["connections-xyz","Bing VirtualEarth", "", "", "", "http://ecn.t3.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a{q}.jpeg?g=1", "", "19", "1"])

# Add sources to browser
for source in sources:
   connectionType = source[0]
   connectionName = source[1]
   QSettings().setValue("qgis/%s/%s/authcfg" % (connectionType, connectionName), source[2])
   QSettings().setValue("qgis/%s/%s/password" % (connectionType, connectionName), source[3])
   QSettings().setValue("qgis/%s/%s/referer" % (connectionType, connectionName), source[4])
   QSettings().setValue("qgis/%s/%s/url" % (connectionType, connectionName), source[5])
   QSettings().setValue("qgis/%s/%s/username" % (connectionType, connectionName), source[6])
   QSettings().setValue("qgis/%s/%s/zmax" % (connectionType, connectionName), source[7])
   QSettings().setValue("qgis/%s/%s/zmin" % (connectionType, connectionName), source[8])
# Update GUI
iface.reloadConnections()
```

and here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.4\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 63, in runsource
code = self.compile(source, filename, symbol)
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.4\apps\Python39\lib\codeop.py", line 178, in __call__
return _maybe_compile(self.compiler, source, filename, symbol)
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.4\apps\Python39\lib\codeop.py", line 106, in _maybe_compile
raise err1
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.4\apps\Python39\lib\codeop.py", line 93, in _maybe_compile
code1 = compiler(source + "\n", filename, symbol)
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.4\apps\Python39\lib\codeop.py", line 143, in __call__
codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, True)
File "<input>", line 11
iface.reloadConnections()
```

Answer (score 0):

I added these two lines to xyz-maps.py to fix errors QGIS is throwing on running the script at startup.

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings
from qgis.utils import iface
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  No errors are being with returned with your suggestions but no WMS are added to the QGIS v3.28.7 project.